# Rails: Share variables between controller and view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing only two variables between controller and view - best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051053/passing-only-two-variables-between-controller-and-view-best-practice)

There is my action:

```
  def list
    @codes = Code.order("created_at")
    @languages = Language.order('name').collect {|l| [l.name, l.coderay]}
  end
```

There is my view(I removed some lines):

```
<% @codes.each do |code| %>
    <div class="code">
        <%= link_to code.title, :action => 'show', :id => code.id %>
        <% if  code.author %>
            @<%= code.author %>
        <% end  %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<%= render :partial => 'shared/error_messages', :locals => {:object => @code} %>
<%= form_for :code, :url => {:action => 'create' }, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %><br>
    <%= f.select(:language, @languages, {:selected => 'text'}) %>
    <%= f.text_field :author %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit code" %>
<% end %>
```

There are 3 variables in it: `@codes`(list of posts), `@code`(current post, used in another action) and @languages.

My IDE writes:

> At most two instance variables should be shared between controller and
>   view
>   This inspection warns if there are more than two instance
>   variables shared between a controller and a view. A controller should
>   only manage one instance variable, plus a second one for the
>   current_user variable.

Usually I share more variables between Controller and View(in PHP), sometimes 10+.
How it's done in Rails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051053/passing-only-two-variables-between-controller-and-view-best-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save an instance var by making languages a helper:

```
def languages
  Language.order('name').collect {|l| [l.name, l.coderay]}
end
```

Comment: I use it only in 1 place of my code(in view). Do you sure it's a good practice to do it as helper?

Comment: Creating a helper for saving an instance var is IMHO far from a best practice too if than the helper is only used in one place. Or as Rail Spikes [put it](http://railspikes.com/2008/8/22/how-to-fix-your-rails-helpers): "Helpers are markup generators. If they’re not involved in generating markup, they’re not helpers and can be pushed into a model".

Comment: @michael - I can agree with that. Putting it in a model makes sense to me. In fact there's probably a cleaner way in which putting it directly in the view would be fine.

Comment: What if it's 5 lines length(long chaining)? It's not a helper. It's not a part of model. I think it should be in controller.

Comment: If we will have many helpers in view, does it good for MVC architecure?

Answer (score 2):

Its a guideline some developers follow some of the time.

But I would read up on Rails Routing a bit more.  Understanding how Rails routing works should give you a better idea on how to structure your code.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

I modified your code a bit, not tested.  But hopefully gives you some good ideas.

Controller:

```
def new
   @code = Code.new
   @codes = Code.order("created_at") 
end

def create
   @code = Code.new(params[:code])
   if @code.save?
      # Do your thing.
   else
      # render your :new action passing your @code variable
   end
end
```

View:

```
 <% @codes.each do |code| %>
    <div class="code">

    # Use Rails Routing - In console, type rake routes to get list of routes.       
    <%= link_to code.title, code_path(code.id) %>  # example.

    <% if code.author %>
        <%= code.author %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
 <% end %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => @code %>

  <%= form_for @code, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
     <%= f.text_area :content %><br>

     # language_list = helper method.
     <%= f.select(:language, language_list, {:selected => 'text'}) %>
     <%= f.text_field :author %><br>
     <%= f.submit "Submit code" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: You forgot to implement language_list. It seems like that would be the most important part of your answer.

Comment: Looking at the code he provided, seemed like he would benefit more by getting a deeper understanding of how Rails routing worked and how things should be structured in general.  But your right, adding a comment above my change would be clearer.   But simply providing a direct answer to a very broad issue is only so helpful.

Comment: I think you imagined it was broader than it really was. The question was how to eliminate 1 instance var.

Comment: Well if the question is specific or broad, hopefully he found it useful.  If I notice someone is doing something the hard way, I try and help them out.

Comment: I understand that you're trying to help but that's not how SO works. This kind of answer doesn't belong here.

Comment: Why don't you let the person who asked the question decide whats useful or not.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should fit right in. *sigh*

Comment: I decided that this code should be a static method in Language model. What do you think about it? If it's very awful solution, I have second solution: leave it as in my 1st post.